Basic Programming Concepts
Why does my Python code raise a TypeError when trying to concatenate a string and an integer?
I tried concatenating a string and an integer like this:
message = name + "is" + age

I was expecting the output to be something like "Hello is 25", but it raised a TypeError.

Python is strongly typed (or at least, towards the strong end of the weak/strong continuum). "Addition" of integers and strings simply is not defined;  you are responsible for turning the int value 25 into a str value that can be concatenated to another str value.

"pythonic" way of achieving your goal here is message = f"{name} is {age}". Look at the linked question for alternatives and details

It's because age is probably an integer.  Try message = name + "is" + str(age)
